# websocket connection to 'wss://url_from_aws_domain/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have implemented a real time notification using socket.io(https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io) on my local and it is working fine. But when I try to implement it on the live server deployed at AWS domain, the frontend that is establishing socket connection to server got error, websocket is unable to connect on the server throwing error:

> websocket connection to
> 'wss://url_from_aws_server/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket'
> failed?

**Front-end Side**(notification sender)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io('https://app.url_from_aws_server.com:4492', { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });
$(document).on("click",'#confirmSlot',function(){

socket.emit("notify_platform", {
    "shop": locationName,
    "therapist": therapistName,
    "date": therapistDate,
    "time": therapistTime,
});
}
</script>
```

**Server Side**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
...
const sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../ssl/key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../ssl/cert.pem')),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

const https = require('https').createServer(sslOptions, app);

const io = require('socket.io')(https, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'https://app.url_from_aws_server.com:4492',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
});
...
https.listen(process.env.SSL_PORT, () => {
    console.log(
        `HTTPS Server started at ${process.env.SSL_PORT}, Database - ${process.env.MONGODB_URI}`
    );
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('Auth value:' + socket.id);
        socket.on('notify_platform', function(details){
            socket.broadcast.emit('notify_platform', details);
        })
    })
});
```

[image]

Comment: Is your server an EC2 instance ? Did you allow connection on port 4492 in Security Groups ?